# jsdoc for commonjs require

Tags: node.js, code-completion, commonjs, jsdoc, webstorm

I use webstorm ide with nodejs. When I create modules and require them, I don't have code completion.

For example:

test.js

```
/** @module test*/
module.exports = {
    run: function () {}
};
```

main.js

```
var test = require(__dirname+"/test.js");
test. //code completion does not offer "run"
```

I haven't found anything about module usages in jsdoc 3 documentation yet. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var test = require("./test.js");
test. //code completion offers "run"
```

So you have to use "." instead of __dirname.